# Configure AAA on a router - Extended ACLs

Tags: routing, firewall, acl, dns, aaa

How do I write a named extended ACL which will allow for traffic between a DNS from a LAN (IP address) to a DNS server at (IP address), ping from a host PC (IP address) to any destination and allow for telnet packets from a telnet server with any source address going to any destination?

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> allow for traffic between a DNS from a LAN (IP address) to a DNS server at (IP address)

```
permit udp <LANIPaddress> <LANIPwildcard> <DNSIPaddress> 0.0.0.0 eq 53
permit tcp <LANIPaddress> <LANIPwildcard> <DNSIPaddress> 0.0.0.0 eq 53
```

> ping from a host PC (IP address) to any destination

```
permit icmp <hostPCaddress> 0.0.0.0 any echo
```

> allow for telnet packets from a telnet server with any source address going to any destination

```
permit tcp any eq 23 any
```

Depending on where exactly you apply the rules, you might also require ACL rules for their reverse directions. Don't forget that an ACL denies/filters *everything* without an explicit `permit`.

Since you've flagged your question `aaa`: ACLs cannot provide that, they just provide basic filtering - possibly Authorization (in cooperation with other mechanisms) but no Authentication or Accounting.

Comment: If the LANIPaddress is 192.1.1.0, is the LANIPwildcard 10.0.0.1 OR 0.0.3.255? Is it both?

Comment: The wildcard is the inverse (ones' complement) of a subnet mask if you use it with subnets. For e.g. a /20 subnet you'd use 0.0.15.255 as wildcard. In contrast to subnet masks, wildcard bits don't have to be contiguous. Any wildcard bit that is set makes the according address bit match either 0 or 1.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to allow SSH from any source address to another router's fa0/0 address and include an ACE on line 800 that will deny all other IP traffic, how would I do that? @Zac67

Comment: Denying all other IP traffic doesn't require anything. It's the default, implied final ACE in any ACL. SSH uses TCP port 22, just replace that in the above examples.

Comment: One last thing, how would I edit the ACL to match packets from a host PC (IP address) to access the server on 2 TCP ports?

Comment: You use two rules.